# Excel tool reducing many formulas to one formula

Tags: excel

Suppose in MS Excel we have cells with values:

A1=3,
A2=4

And cells with formulas:

**A3**=A1+A2

A4=**A3***A1

Is there any automatic way (macro or other tool) that would change the last formula in A4 into:

A4=(A1+A2)*A1

So it nests all former functions in brakets creating one long formula out of many formulas in a worksheet. The final formula would refer only to cells with values (not formulas).

Comment: This question is off topic and should be closed.

Comment: While you could run a replace (normal or via code) on `A3` with `(A1+A2)` there are significant potential issues. ie `SUM(A3:A4)` would fail as `SUM(A1+A2):A4`

Answer (score 1):

@iDevlop is quite clear your answer is "No" but it may be of some help to use say highlighting to identify cells with formulae (Home > Editing -Find & Select, Got To Special, Formulas, OK) and then use Formulas > Formula Auditing - Trace Precedents.